# Custom layout item list result of suggestion of search view of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I make a search with suggestion in action bar get from web service. I have already set suggestion with text. But I need add icon to item look like picture. So how can I customise layout of item in suggestion of search view in action bar ?

Example:

[image]

Comment: You have to use custom layout with image and text and set layout as suggestion.

Comment: @  Surender Kumar. Can you demo it for me. I research on google but i don't see any demonstration for it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to write an adapter for your custom view. Example code;

class KitapFiltreAdapter(context:Context,
@LayoutRes private val layoutRes:Int,
val kitapListe:ArrayList):ArrayAdapter(context,layoutRes,kitapListe){

```
private val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater;

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val view: View;
    view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, parent, false);

    val kitapImage:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchItemImageId) as ImageView;
    val kitapAdTw:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchKitapAdItemId) as TextView;
    val yazarAdTw:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchKitapYazarAdItemId) as TextView;
    val kitap:KitapModel = getItem(position) as KitapModel;

    Glide.with(context).load(kitap.kitapResimPath).into(kitapImage);
    if(kitap.kitapAd!!.length>24){
        kitapAdTw.text     = kitap.kitapAd!!.substring(0,23)+"...";
    }else{
        kitapAdTw.text     = kitap.kitapAd;
    }

    yazarAdTw.text = kitap.yazarAd;

    return view;
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): KitapModel? {
    return kitapListe.get(position);
}

}
```

then you can set this adapter like;

```
searchView.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.search_src_text).setAdapter(KitapFiltreAdapter(applicationContext,R.layout.kitap_search_item_layout,liste));
```